# http page loses 2nd css files after refresh

Tags: xml, http, caching, http-headers

I have a small http server running, for specific request server reads example.xml content and sends to browser with text/xml mime type. xml file has link to xslfile.

xslfile:- has two lines in body 
   `<h1>red</h1>` 
    `<h2>blue</h2>`

with all proper prototype and it's head loads 2 css files.
a.css file is with h1{color:red;}
b.css file is with h2{color:blue;}

for first hit browser gets proper content with red and blue headlines,so there is no error in xml, xsl, css files and in http server.
problem is "If I refresh the same page it loads same content with only  as red and  becomes black it means for the next refreshes browser not getting b.css file. could anyone please answer my query..???

it's happening on firefox only

Comment: Please post your full xsl file

Comment: Please find the xsl file below

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="a.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="b.css"/>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<style type="text/css"></style>
 <body style="margin:0">
<h2>Volume Details</h2>
<h1>Volume Details</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. actullay I was using Xinetd for my http server and it was putting some limit for http requests

Thanks:)